# C : Deleting element from Binary Tree

Tags: c, tree, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I have a binary tree with 2 rows: `key` and `combination`. Problem appears when I try to delete elements where combination is longer then 5 digits.
I call this `ifMore(root);` And when it find element where combination longer then 5 digits, it calls `DeleteTooLong()`.
So when I start program it delete 2 (`b`, `l`) elements and then appears (on `i`) "Segmentation fault: 11"

It's my tree:

```
h - 001
d - 002
b - 004444
a - 0080
c - 009
f - 005
e - 010
g - 011
l - 003333
j - 006
i - 0121212
k - 013
n - 007
m - 0141414
o - 015



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int point =0;
typedef struct key_combinations
{
    char *key;
    char *combination;
} KEY_COMBINATION;


typedef struct tree
{
    KEY_COMBINATION kc;
    struct tree *left,*right;
}Tree;

Tree *root;

void AddNode (Tree * proot, Tree * pnew) ;
void GetData ();
void PrintTree();
void ShowTree(Tree *rooot, int lvl);
void PutTree(Tree *rooot);
void ifMore(Tree *rooot);
void DeleteTooLong(Tree **rooot);
void FreeNode (Tree * node) ;


void main()
{
    GetData ();
    PrintTree();
    ifMore(root);
    PrintTree();
}

void GetData ()
{
    Tree * pel;
    KEY_COMBINATION * pkc;

    char bufk[3],bufc[25];
    FILE* f;

    int choise;
    printf("choose file balanced[1] not balanced[2] :   ");
    scanf("%d",&choise);

    if(choise==2)
        f = fopen("TreeNB","r");
    else
        f = fopen("TreeB","r");

    while(fscanf(f,"%s %s",bufk,bufc)!=EOF)
    {
        pkc->key = (char * ) malloc(strlen(bufk)+1);
        strcpy(pkc->key, bufk);

        pkc->combination =(char * ) malloc(strlen(bufc)+1);
        strcpy(pkc->combination, bufc);

        pel=(Tree *)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
        pel->kc = * pkc;

        pel->left = NULL;
        pel->right = NULL;

        AddNode(root,pel);
    }
}

void AddNode (Tree * proot, Tree * pnew)
{
    if (root == NULL)
       root = pnew;
    else
        if (strcmp(proot->kc.key, pnew->kc.key)>0)
            if (proot->left == NULL)
                proot->left = pnew;
            else
                AddNode(proot->left, pnew);
        else
            if (proot->right == NULL)
                proot->right = pnew;
            else
                AddNode(proot->right, pnew);
}

void PrintTree()
{
    puts("\n===============================");
    PutTree(root);
    puts("\n===============================\n");
    ShowTree(root,1);
    puts("===============================");
}

void ShowTree(Tree *rooot, int lvl)
{
    if(rooot==NULL)
        return;

    ShowTree(rooot->right,lvl+1);
    printf("%*c%s\n", lvl*3,' ', rooot->kc.key);
    ShowTree(rooot->left,lvl+1);
}

void PutTree(Tree *rooot)
{
    if(rooot==NULL)
        return;
    printf("\n\t%s -\t%s", rooot->kc.key, rooot->kc.combination);
    PutTree(rooot->left);
    PutTree(rooot->right);
}

void ifMore(Tree *rooot)
{

    if(rooot==NULL)
        return;
    if(strlen(rooot->kc.combination)>5){
        printf("\n\t%s -\t%s", rooot->kc.key, rooot->kc.combination);
        DeleteTooLong(&rooot);
    }
    ifMore(rooot->left);
    ifMore(rooot->right);
}

void DeleteTooLong(Tree **rooot)
{
    Tree *treeroot=*rooot, *newroot, *parent;
    int subtrees;
    if(rooot==NULL)
        return;

    if(treeroot->left==NULL && treeroot->right==NULL)
        subtrees=0;
    else if(treeroot->left==NULL)
        subtrees=-1;
    else if(treeroot->right==NULL)
        subtrees=1;
    else
        subtrees=2;

    switch(subtrees)
    {
    case  0: *rooot=NULL;             break;
    case  1: *rooot=treeroot->left;   break;
    case  -1: *rooot=treeroot->right; break;
    case  2:
        newroot=treeroot->left;
        parent=treeroot;
        while(newroot->right!=NULL)
        {
            parent=newroot;
            newroot=newroot->right;
        }

        newroot->right=treeroot->right;
        if(parent!=treeroot)
        {
            parent->right=newroot->left;
            newroot->left=treeroot->left;
        }
        *rooot=newroot;
    }
    printf("\n point : %d",point++);
    printf("\t free...");
    FreeNode(treeroot);
}

void FreeNode (Tree * node)
{
    free(node->kc.key);
    free(node->kc.combination);
    free(node);
}
```

Comment: Have you used a debugger?

Comment: no , Im on MonoDeveloper(MAC) i'm new to it so i don't really even know how to use it here...

Comment: However , i get error on starting debugger

Comment: You never initialize pkc, tweak the compiler settings to give you as many warnings as possible.

Comment: also your fscanf is broken, as "-" is a string -- try adding debugging printf()'s!

Comment: Valgrind will do analysis on mem problems and seg faults, might want to start rolling with that, if you're new then using tools like this early and working it into your regular workflow will be easier than trying to adopt it later.

Comment: when i try to set pkc to NULL or something like that i get sego. fault 11 so , still don't know what to do

Comment: You can allocate it dynamically, (try "KEY_COMBINATION pkc[1]" for some stupid fun :) or just declare it on the stack and use "." rather than "->" since you're just copying its contents into the pel variable

Comment: The most important thing, anyway, is that you focus on *how* you're trying to solve this: you'll never use this program once you get it working, but learning to print when needed, or use a debugger, or valgrind -- any of those will be useful to you for as long as you program.

Comment: Now i set more detailed program mistakes view , getting bus error 10 on start...

Comment: again: if pkc is a pointer, you can't "pkc->whatever" before you made sure that pkc points to something; either do "pkc = malloc(...)" before the loop, or just don't use a pointer ("KEY_COMBINATION pkc"). Again(2): your fscanf doesn't work like you think it does -- print bufk and bufc to see what happens and try to figure out why, then (only then!) fix it, and you'll finally be able to check if your tree implementation works or not. And remember to also follow n-m's advice, it will take you some time to get started, but you'll be amazed by what a debugger can do :)

Comment: tks for pck , i fixed. but i didn't get about fsanf i printed buff and bufk its working good:


 h 001
 d 002
 l 003333
 b 004444
 f 0050505
 j 0060606
 n 007
 a 0080
 c 009
 e 010
 g 011
 i 012
 k 013
 m 014
 o 015
so what's wrong with it?

Also , i can't start debugger , there is some mistake i'll try to fix it later , but i need to pass this program tomorrow!

Comment: I add other funks all  are working except DeleteTooLong() segmentation default when trying to print TREE after deleting

Comment: i fixed , all is working tks all

Comment: I'm here again to say  that still not working ,if you try to delete leave without children. so , need help